# Touchpad twitchy on an HP G62 with a SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

Tags: 12.04, synaptics

I experience some problems with my touchpad on Ubuntu 12.04. 
Everytime I tap/double tap the touchpad the cursor is moving around (not static as should be) (for example if I want to close a window, I click on "x" button from touchpad, the cursor is moving and not always hit the "x" button). Touchpad buttons left click, right click are working well, but tap not. 
Did u guys experience the same problem? How to fix it?

PS: on Ubuntu 11.10 didn't had this issue

Using a HP G62 and touchpad model is "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad". If I use this code `xinput --list` I got this:

> SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=12   [slave pointer (2)]

Comment: Bug reported, affects multiple users https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/992330