# Touchpad sensitivity issue even after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: touchpad

Still having this problem on Ubuntu 12.10 [Touchpad twitchy on an HP G62 with a SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128181/touchpad-twitchy-on-an-hp-g62-with-a-synps-2-synaptics-touchpad) even after I upgraded to 12.10.

Same problem here posted 2 days ago [Touchpad sensitivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205512/touchpad-palm-sensitivity)

I really have no idea what the problem is and why they didn't fix it. Using this OS less and less 'cause of this. Great OS but synaptics su kc s.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem and also tried installing the driver in the link mentioned in the previous comment. I was able to get some good results using the xinput utility to modify the touchpad settings. Specifically with the "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" option. By default it was set to "12, 12". I am currently using a value of "28, 28". And the twitchy pointer behaves a lot better. It's not perfect but usable now. Information on the various driver options can be found here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/synaptics.4.html

I guess you could use the synclient utility as well to do this. FYI the command I used to modify my settings:

```
xinput set-prop 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad' 'Synaptics Noise Cancellation' 28 28
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/quantal/main/base/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics) and install your version (32bit or 64 bit) Synaptic Touchpad driver. It should work. It worked for my MSI-CR420

Comment: Same behavior even after upgrading it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my HP ENVY 17 with synPS/2 touchpad.

First open terminal, second copy and paste this...
xinput --set-prop 11  "Synaptics Finger" 40 50 227

It's not perfect however, but much better. The higher the number you set it to the LESS sensitive it becomes.