# How to fix touchpad (synaptics) problem on acer aspire v 13? Sometimes cursor jumps like crazy

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, acer, synaptics

Sometimes cursor starts jump here and there (very quickly). Disabling and enabling touchpad helps but for short time.

xubuntu 15.04,  3.19.0-30-generic

"xinput list"  shows that core pointer is UNKNOWN

```
user@laptop:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYN1B7F:00 06CB:2991 UNKNOWN              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
---
```

Is there something that I can do?

```
user@laptop:~$ xinput --list-props 13
Device 'SYN1B7F:00 06CB:2991 UNKNOWN':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (291):  48, 1175, 36, 648
    Synaptics Finger (292): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (293):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (294):   61
    Synaptics Tap Durations (295):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (296):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (297):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (298):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (299):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (300): 28, 28
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (301): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (302):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (303): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.142755, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (304):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (305):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (306):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (307): 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (308):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (309): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (310):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (311): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (312):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (313): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (314):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (315): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (316):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (317): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (318):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (319):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (320):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (321):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (322): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (323):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (324):  611, 0, 560, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (325): 7, 7
    Device Product ID (260):    1739, 10641
    Device Node (261):  "/dev/input/event14"
```

here's synaptics.conf

```
user@laptop:~$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf 
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Does this happen while you're typing or also when you're not typing?

Comment: I'd try the noise cancelation option: https://askubuntu.com/questions/206975/touchpad-sensitivity-issue-even-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: I'm not sure about typing. I'm going to test it.
I've tried noise cancelation but it didn't work for me.

Comment: take a look at this and read how to fix/adjust mouse pads on Ubuntu... worked for me on my Lenovo w540 and ubuntu 15.10 http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tweak-your-touchpad-to-taste-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

I have this same laptop, are you using UEFI or bios?
The bios (legacy mode) on that laptop is buggy and causes touchpad issues.

Comment: What touchpad issues have you experienced in legacy mode?
I use legacy mode. Why does it matter?

Comment: @varan There might have been a bios bug in specific versions or something. I honestly can't remember anymore (I no longer have that computer). I just remember that the UEFI install worked more consistently. In retrospect it could have just been a very convenient correlation, as the other solution seems more realistic.