# Cursor Unwanted Behaviour

Tags: 14.04, drivers, touchpad, cursor, malware

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on an Acer laptop. The cursor often unwantedly

- moves and jumps to different locations,
- drags and drops items, or
- randomly clicks on things.

Could anyone suggest a solution for this?
I don't know if this is caused by a bug in the drivers or the operating system, or it is caused by some malware.

Additional Note: I am using the touchpad of my laptop for controlling the cursor and it is for about a few months that the problem has appeared. Before that, I used to run different versions of Ubuntu with no such problem.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the touchpad sensitivity. Check your mouse settings to see if there's an option.

Comment: I can say that, apparently, it is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/462135/touchpad-issue-jumping-cursor-while-typing-ubuntu-14-04-syndaemon-dont-help and of http://askubuntu.com/questions/681737/how-to-fix-touchpad-synaptics-problem-on-acer-aspire-v-13-sometimes-cursor-ju . These two questions do not have accepted answers as is often the case with touchpad problems. However they will give you resolution paths for you to deal with your specific hardware. --- Please complete your question with the output of `xinput --list` in terminal. -- To enter terminal type `ALT+CTRL+T`. To exit type `CTRL+D` at prompt.

Comment: Have you tried using an external mouse and disabling the internal touch pad?  Sounds like a hardware issue...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The reason:

I have a very old laptop and when my **battery and laptop charge**r broke, I **purchased "generic" ones** on ebay and not the original from Lenovo. The battery does not create any problems but when the generic charger is connected, I experience the same issues. On Windows it happens what you describe but on Ubuntu 14.04 (dual boot) I can't even move the cursor...

**Use an external mouse or unplug the charger and see if the problems goes away.**

Maybe you have the same problem.

Comment: Before the appearance of the problem, I used to use the same charger and battery, therefore, they can't be the source of it.